# Is there a pandas function to select latest available date of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code, but I want to automate or simplify the latest date available selection. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

covid_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'

covid_total = pd.read_csv(covid_url, index_col=0)
covid_total = covid_total.loc['Colima', '17-03-2020':02-12-2020']

covid_total
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way to substitute the `02-12-2020` loc for something that can select the latest available date?

I thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:` this solved my problem without sacrificing the data filter from `17-03-2020`:

```
import pandas as pd

covid_total = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(covid_total, index_col=0)

df = df.loc['Colima', '17-03-2020':]

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change to date

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')


#df.loc[df.index.max()]
```